Code: unknown, Error: Invalid response while obtaining request token from "api.linkedin.com"
I'm unsure what I did wrong, here is my settings.py
    "openid_connect": {
    "APPS": [
        {
            "provider_id": "linkedin",
            "name": "LinkedIn",
            "client_id": LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
            "secret": LINKEDIN_SECRET,
            "settings": {
                "server_url": "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth",
            },
        }
    ]
},

My redirect_uri inside the linkedin app config (of course my-website is filled correctly):
https://my-website.com/accounts/linkedin/login/callback/

The error message somehow won't help me:

An error occurred
Code: unknown, Error: Invalid response while obtaining request token from "api.linkedin.com".

Did anybody face this error? What's wrong with my response? How can I find it out?
